# call php function without a specific argument

Tags: php

```
function givemeposts($pos, $limit, $offset){
...
}

givemeposts('slider', 25, 0);
```

The obove works. Now I need the same function, without limit param

```
givemeposts('slider', NULL, 0);
```

Error:
`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1327 Undeclared variable: offset`

Any help?

Comment: this question needs the `givemeposts` implementation to answer.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII, implementation is the same in both cases. Error appears during calling the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining the default for limit would work for you.

```
function givemeposts($pos, $offset, $limit = null) {
...
}
```

Both would work:

```
givemeposts('slider',0, 25);
givemeposts('slider',0);
```

Comment: but next time I need `$limit` param. For example - `givemeposts('slider', 25, 0);`. Is there a way to call the same function ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same function, as the default value is defined you don't need to pass the $limit parameter every call. As you can see the $limit argument was moved to the end of the function arguments list.

Answer (score 0):

Use default arguments:

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default

```
function givemeposts($pos, $limit=NULL, $offset=0){ }
```

and then:

```
givemeposts('slider');
```

or

```
givemeposts('slider', 25);
```

or

```
givemeposts('slider', 25, 0);
```

What you can't do is skip limit by using:

```
givemeposts('slider', 0);
```

because PHP won't, as far as I know, allow the python style of:

```
givemeposts('slider', offset=0);
```

Comment: but next time I need `$limit` param. For example - `givemeposts('slider', 25, 0);`. Is there a way to call the same function ?

Comment: Yes. This gives you the OPTION to leave off any parameters in sequence starting with the first one that has a default:

Comment: In your first scenario `givemeposts('slider');` gives me the same error - `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1327 Undeclared variable: offset`

Comment: The part you haven't listed in your code is how you are using the 3 parameters - i.e., the SQL statement. Without that, I can't guess about the source of that error. The default parameters just solves the PHP problem but you may need extra code to properly handle SQL.